# changing font attributes in jupyter notebook label widget

Tags: python, widget, jupyter

I am trying to modify the font attributes (weight, color, etc) of a jupyter label widget in python 2.7.  As an example, I have tried the following:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
myLabel= widgets.Label(value = 'Some Label',color = '#ff0000') #change font color to red
myLabel
```

When I run this bit of code, I get no errors, however the label color remains the default black.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 methods that I know of.

1. HTML widget
2. Label widget with latex

```py
text = 'Some text'

htmlWidget = widgets.HTML(value = f"<b><font color='red'>{text}</b>")

labelWidget = widgets.Label(value = r'\(\color{red} {' + text  + '}\)')
```

[image]

**Update: and now with Ipyvuetify....**

```py
import ipyvuetify as v
text = 'Some text'
v.Html(tag="div", children=[text], style_ = "color: red; font-weight: bold")
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to control the font size. For the HTML version you can use `htmlWidget = widgets.HTML(value = f"<b><font color='red'><font size=10>{text}</b>")`. This appears to be measured in pixels. Note that increasing this font size will probably saturate a global layout bound. E.g. you might ask for `font size=100` but it still looks like `font size=10`.

Comment: @JohnMahoney , if you use Ipyvuetify, you can use this :  
v.Html(tag="div", children=['Some text'], style_ = " color: red;   font-family: courier;  font-size: 100px; font-weight: bold")

Comment: HTML widgets are a versatile replacement for Label widgets when formatting is needed, for instance one can write : `HTML(value= r'<p style="font-size:24px"><b>My Title</b></p>)`

Answer (score 4):

This is a late reply, but for everyone who's still having this issue, you can add styling to the widget labels and description by using latex formatting. Here's an example to color the label text in red:

```
myLabel= widgets.Label(value = r'\(\color{red} {highlighted}\)')
```

Answer (score 3):

There are limitations with both the HTML widget (can't be aggregated in a collection, e.g. VBox, Hbox, Tab), and the use of LaTeX formating inside a label (will format as an equation - which is typically not what is wanted).

A way to overcome both these limitations, is to use the add_class method of the widget, to allow you to create any CSS styling:

```
from ipywidgets import Label
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML("<style>.red_label { color:red }</style>"))
l = Label(value="My Label")
l.add_class("red_label")
display(l)
```

Comment: The `widgets.HTML` class *can* be aggregated in a collection. I found this out struggling with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

one of the developers of the widgets [says here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/577) that all the layout options shall be done [in the layout attribute](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html).

Currently i am exploring the capabilities of this attribute, but there seems to be no way to change font, font color or font size.

It may be that you have to write your own css file.

Answer (score 1):

If the label was using a specific element of HTML, which it doesn't, you could use

```py
import IPython
import ipywidgets as widgets

IPython.display.HTML('<style> widget-label   { color: red; } </style>')
myLabel= widgets.Label(value = 'Some Label') ;
myLabel
```

However `widget-label` is not an element but a CSS class in this case, therefore the above code doesn't work. Hence, the option given by @AlanDyke is the next best one, either using the class it already has.

```py
import IPython
import ipywidgets as widgets

IPython.display.HTML('<style> .widget-label   { color: red; } </style>')
myLabel= widgets.Label(value = 'Some Label') 
myLabel
```

Note: In google-colab you must replace `IPython.display.HTML ...` with
`display(HTML('<style> .widget-label   { color: red; } </style>'))`.

Alternatively, creating a new one *and* attaching it.

```py
import IPython
import ipywidgets as widgets

#IPython.display.HTML('<style> .widget-label, .redlabel   { color: red; } </style>')
IPython.display.HTML('<style> .redlabel   { color: red; } </style>')
myLabel= widgets.Label(value = 'Some Label') ;
myLabel.add_class('redlabel');
myLabel
```

[image]

For similar question see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70228454/4752223

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for the original question in Python 2.7, but since this is one of the first search results for styling `ipywidgets`:

In recent versions of `ipywidgets`, [*some* style properties can be set with the style attribute](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#the-style-attribute). For example, for `Labels`: [ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.LabelStyle](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ipywidgets.html#ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.LabelStyle)