# How to update HTML text that is displayed in Python Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I'm wondering if there is a way to display HTML text that can update itself in Python with Jupyter Notebooks.

In other words, I want to be able to say:

```html
<p>Hi there!</p>
```

and then....

```html
<p>Go away!</p>
```

but instead of producing two lines of text, I want the first line to be changed into the second.

Any ways to achieve this? (I assume it requires some kind of JS, but I'm not sure how to do that)...

EDIT:

I originally asked how to update Python text like: `print("Hello World")` but I specifically want to update HTML text because I want to be able to apply CSS properties to the text.

Comment: Have you looked at jupyter widgets? You might have good luck with the HTML widget: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#HTML

Comment: Yeah I've looked into Ipython widgets, unfortunately there does not seem to be a good way to change CSS properties of the widget text so you can't really change the size, color, etc.

Comment: You can generate arbitrary HTML output with the html widget, which is what your question indicates.

Comment: Change colour of text.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684791/changing-font-attributes-in-jupyter-notebook-label-widget/55221167#55221167

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time

out = widgets.HTML()
display(out)
out.value="<p>Hi there!</p>"
time.sleep(1)
out.value = "<p>Go away!</p>"
```