# Monospace in ipywidgets.Textarea?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

how could I get my widgets to use monospace fonts?

```
from ipywidgets import Textarea
Textarea('The world is bigger than you.')
```

I want to show some table style data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also works:

```
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.core.display import HTML

display(HTML("<style>textarea, input { font-family: monospace; }</style>"))
```

Comment: not working for google collab notebooks :(

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-style-attribute) talks about the `style` attribute of widgets that gives you access to CSS properties. However only some properties are exposed to the widget via `style`.

The workaround is to edit the CSS style within the notebook / jupyter / colab cell and then display the widget.

```py
# Adding monospace style
import IPython
IPython.display.HTML('<style> select, textarea, input { font-family: Courier New; } </style>')

# Seems that either the 
# font-family: monospace or font-family: Courier New 
# produce the monospace effect.
# IPython.display.HTML('<style> select, textarea, input { font-family: monospace; } </style>')

# Display your widget
widgets.SelectMultiple(options=sss)
widgets.Textarea(value="Here it is")
```

[image]

It works for Textarea, Input, Select, SelectMultiple and any other widgets as they all are html.

---

Another way is to define the style for a CSS *class*, and then attach that class to the desired widgets.

```py
IPython.display.HTML('''<style>
.mytext > select,.mytext > textarea   {
    font-style: italic;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
}
</style>''')

w2=widgets.Textarea(value="Here it is")
w2.add_class("mytext")

w1=widgets.SelectMultiple(options=sss)
w1.add_class('mytext')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may be a brittle solution, but it seems to work.  Add a html magic section giving the css styling:

```
%%html
<style>
textarea, input {
    font-family: monospace;
}
</style>
```