# Change font-size in ipywidget.textarea

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

According to this [Monospace in ipywidgets.Textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471862/monospace-in-ipywidgets-textarea), I was able to change the font of my textarea. But no way to change the font-size.
Do you know a way please ? It seems that font-size has no effect.

cf the code below:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(HTML("<style>textarea, input { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; }</style>"))

from ipywidgets import Textarea
Textarea('The world is bigger than you.')
```

Thanks,
Hadrien

Answer (score 1):

The font-size attribute is overridden by `--jp-ui-font-size1` from `:root` so you should update this one instead. Combine this with some ipython magic:

```
%%html
<style>
textarea, input {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
:root {
    --jp-ui-font-size1: 20px;
}
</style>
```